# hacer un update a una tabla y me sale parameter index out of range 1< 0

Tags: java, base-de-datos, updatepanel

al momento de realizar un update a una bd  mediante java, me aparece este error:

[image: error]

Eh revisado el codigo atentamente y no logro detectar el error por el cual me aparece: paramenter index out of range 1<0

Que me sugieren colegas, soy junior developer :'( no sean tan duros conmigo.

Saludos.

EDITADO:

```
  private void btnActualizarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           

    try {

        PreparedStatement pps = conexion.prepareStatement("UPDATE ColaboradorDatosBanco SET NombreBanco=?, NroCuenta=?, CodCci=?,CREARCUENTASUELDO=?");



        pps.setString(1, txtBanco.getText());
        pps.setString(2, txtNroCuenta.getText());
        pps.setString(3, txtCci.getText());
        pps.setString(4, txtTengoCuenta.getText());

        pps.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos Actualizados");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR SAPE: " + e);
    }


}
```

Estimado colega, pude modificar, pero ahora todo se modifica XD, entonces para eso serviria el where? para dictaminar en que llave se hara el update?

EDITADO:

mira el resultado XD, modifica todo :(

[image: :S]

Comment: Por favor, pásate por el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para que aprendas como se debe preguntar. Siempre debes incluir tú código como texto, por si alguien necesita reproducir tu ejemplo no tenga que transcribirlo.

Comment: me causa duda, si estas haciendo un UPDATE ¿por qué debes actualizar el id y luego lo usas como referencia de comparación en tu clausula WHERE?

Comment: Hola :D si, deberia eliminarlo?

Comment: Efectivamente, el `WHERE` te sirve para discriminar cuales registros deseas actualizar. En tu caso debes utilizar el id del colaborador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error se debe a que la consulta la estás declarando sin parámetros, ya que estás concatenando los valores que deseas setear a cada campo dentro de la misma consulta: `"NombreBanco='" + txtBanco.getText() + "', "`. Si lo haces de este modo, que no es el recomendado, sería incorrecto que luego intentes pasar valores a los parámetros, ya que no existen. El modo correcto de hacer lo que quieres sería: `"NombreBanco = ?,"`.

Por ejemplo:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE Colaborador set nombre=? , apellidos=?");

preparedStatement.setString(1, txtNombre.getText());
preparedStatement.setString(2, txtApellidos.getText());
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aclaracion Betanzos, pero el where deberia eliminarlo? ya que de igual manera me ocurre un conflico.

Comment: Ya eso depende de la lógica de tu aplicación. ¿Qué quieres decir por "conflicto"?

Comment: En realidad solo deseo hacer un simple update a mi bd, el conflicto que tengo ahora y son 2 casos: 
CASO SI LE AGREGO EL WHERE, al parecer con el where esta sumando 1 index mas, cosa que no quiero ya que en realidad solo modificaria el nombre del banco, el nro de cuenta, el cci y el campo "TENGOCUENTA"
JAVA.SQL.SQLEXCEPTION: NO VALUE SPECIFIED FOR PARAMETER 7
SI NO ESTA EL WHERE y al parecer esta como igualando 2 pk que en este caso el pk es IdColabDatoBanco, pero entonces, elimino el where? 
JDBC4.MYSQLINTEGRITYCONSTRAINTVIOLATIONEXCEPTION: DUPLICATE ENTRY '1' FOR KEY PRIMARY

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta y reemplaza la imagen donde muestras el código del método `btnActualizarMouseClicked()` por el código del método en si, para modificar mi respuesta y ponerte el código de ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

fíjate bien en tu código a mi también me parecía el mismo error

- es un error en la base de satos, en la consulta
  este erea mi error:
  "insert into tusuario values('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?')");
  así es como Devia ser:
  "insert into tusuario values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");